# Python encoding conversion

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x, marc

I wrote a Python script that processes CSV files with non-ascii characters, encoded in UTF-8. However the encoding of the output is broken. So, from this in the input:

```
"d\xc4\x9bjin hornictv\xc3\xad"
```

I get this in the output:

```
"d\xe2\x99\xafjin hornictv\xc2\xa9\xc6\xaf"
```

Can you suggest where the encoding error might come from? Have you seen similar behaviour previously?

EDIT: I'm using `csv` standard library with the `UnicodeWriter` class featured in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). I use Python version 2.6.6.

EDIT 2: The code to reproduce the behaviour:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import csv
from pymarc import MARCReader # The pymarc package available PyPI: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymarc/2.71
from UnicodeWriter import UnicodeWriter # The UnicodeWriter from: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

def getRow(tag, record):
  if record[tag].is_control_field():
    row = [tag, record[tag].value()]
  else:
    row = [tag] + record[tag].subfields
  return row

inputFile = open("input.mrc", "r")
outputFile = open("output.csv", "wb")
reader = MARCReader(inputFile, to_unicode = True)
writer = UnicodeWriter(outputFile, delimiter = ",", quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for record in reader:
  if bool(record["001"]):
    tags = [field.tag for field in record.get_fields()]
    tags.sort()
    for tag in tags:
      writer.writerow(getRow(tag, record))

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

The input data is [available here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/893551/input.mrc) (large file).

Comment: By the way, did you try using the built-in csv module? http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `csv` standard library. And I have even tried the `UnicodeWriter` class available from http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: OK, I hope my code will make sense. If not, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems adding `force_utf8 = True` argument to the `MARCReader` constructor solved the problem:

```
reader = MARCReader(inputFile, to_unicode = True, force_utf8 = True)
```

According to the inspection of the source code (via `inspect`) it does something like:

```
string.decode("utf-8", "strict")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the file with UTF-8 encoding:

```
import codecs
codecs.open('myfile.txt', encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: When I replace the input file open the regular way with it opened with the `codecs` standard library, I get an error `couldn't find 0x11b in g0=66 g1=69`.